# course vs heading. Which one I need?

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

I'm using `CLLocationManager` to detect GPS position. `CLLocation` has `course` property, it seems that it's what I need, it returns in which direction user traveling.

I have trouble receiving them, mostly I get "-1" value.

I found `startHeadingUpdate` API and not sure why do I need it? And do I need it for my specific case? Is it like compass to see how phone oriented?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Course_(navigation) So are you interested in the direction a vehicle is pointed, or the direction it is moving in?  This is less relevant with a vehicle such as a car (being driven well), but can be relevant for a hiker, and critically important for a boater, as boats can have drift introduced by currents and winds.

Comment: I'm interested in direction vehicle moving in

Comment: The direction the vehicle is moving in is a course.  The direction it's pointing is a heading.  One typically hopes both are the same, when speaking of road vehicles. ;)

Comment: Still confusing.. So, it doesn't matter how iDevice oriented inside vehicle>?

Comment: A bearing is a compass direction.  Orientation of the measuring device is important for bearings, not course or heading.